# Why does the following bring back data only when both parameters are set?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

The two procedures, SearchMaster and SearchDetails work if I run it in Sql Management Studio and SearchMaster even runs fine when I am Testing the Query when I set up the stored procedure in design view, but when I run it, no rows are created if I enter just info for the frn or business.  If I enter for both, I do get data if there is a match.  Are the parameters etup correctly? Also, if I am initializing the parameters to null in the procedure, is it still necessary to use ConvertEmptyStringToNull?

Here is the SearchMaster StoredProcedure:

```
CREAETE PROCEDURE SearchMaster
@business nvarchar(300) = NULL,
@frn nvarchar(10) = NULL
AS
SELECT h.Business,
       hrl.frn
FROM registration hrl
INNER JOIN holder h on h.call = hrl.call
WHERE (@business IS NULL OR h.Business like '%' + @business + '%') 
AND (@frn IS NULL OR hrl.frn = @frn)
```

Here is the SearchDetails StoredProcedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchDetails
@business nvarchar(300) = NULL,
@frn nvarchar(10) = NULL
AS
SELECT hrl.call 
FROM registration hrl 
INNER JOIN holder h ON h.call = hrl.call
WHERE (@business IS NULL OR h.Business LIKE '%' + @business + '%') 
  AND (@frn IS NULL OR hrl.frn = @frn)
```

Here is the SqlDataSource for the SearchMaster procedure:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDsDetails" 
               runat="server" 
               ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cnxString %>
               SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
               SelectCommand="SearchMaster">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter Name="business" ControlID="txtBusiness" 
                  Type="String" PropertyName="Text"  
                  ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
<asp:ControlParameter Name="frn" ControlID="txtFRN" 
                  Type="String" PropertyName="Text"
                  ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"/>
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is the SqlDataSource for the SearchDetails procedure:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDsDetails" 
               runat="server" 
               ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cnxString %>
               SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
               SelectCommand="SearchDetails">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="frn" Type="String" DefaultValue="" 
           ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
<asp:Parameter Name="business" Type="String" DefaultValue="" 
           ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is the button click that binds the SqlDsMaster:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sqlDsMaster.DataBind();
}
```

Here is the gvMaster_RowCreated that creates the rows for the details:

```
protected void gvMaster_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        SqlDataSource ctrl = 
        e.Row.FindControl("sqlDsDetails") as SqlDataSource;

        if (ctrl != null && e.Row.DataItem != null)
        {
            ctrl.SelectParameters["frn"].DefaultValue = 
            ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["frn"].ToString();

            ctrl.SelectParameters["business"].DefaultValue = 
            ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["business"].ToString();
         }
     }
 }
```

I ran the SQL Profiler and when only one parameter was entered, the profiler did not even show the procedure running.  When I entered both parameters, the procedure was shown running in the profiler.

Comment: Based on your last comment I'm 100% certain this will fix it: Make sure to set CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False" on your DataSource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that it is still passing in an empty string for what you consider the null case. You could rule this out by doing:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchDetails
@business nvarchar(300) = NULL,
@frn nvarchar(10) = NULL
AS

SELECT @business = NULLIF(@business, ''),
       @frn = NULLIF(@frn, '')

 SELECT hrl.call // etc
```

If it starts working, it was passing in empty strings.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I will try this out now and let you know.

Comment: Since I am not to up on t-sql, can you post where I would put this to test it.

Comment: I also have ConvertEmptyStringsToNull = "true" which I thought would prevent empty strings from being passed, plus in the procedure, I am initializing the parameters to null.  In addition, if I run the procedure in Sql Management Studio with an empty string for 1 parameter, it still returns data.

Comment: wow I've been using tsql for 10 years and never used NullIf, I use IsNull frequently, but NullIf must have slipped by me somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect Marc Gravell is right on the money.

Try the following tests:

```
 SearchMaster @business = null        , @frn = null
 SearchMaster @business = 'something' , @frn = null
 SearchMaster @business = 'something' , @frn = 'something'
 SearchMaster @business = null        , @frn = 'something'
 SearchMaster @business = 'something' , @frn = 'something'
 SearchMaster @business = 'something' , @frn = ''
 SearchMaster @business = ''          , @frn = 'something'
```

Note that the last 2 will not return anything - unless you have blank businesses and frn in the DB ;)

If you place the select statement from Marc just after the AS line your statement it should work as you expect it to.

So something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchMaster
@business nvarchar(300) = NULL,
@frn nvarchar(10) = NULL
AS
SELECT @business = NULLIF(@business,'') , @frn = NULLIF(@frn,'')

SELECT h.Business,
       hrl.frn
FROM registration hrl
INNER JOIN holder h on h.call = hrl.call
WHERE (@business IS NULL OR h.Business like '%' + @business + '%') 
AND (@frn IS NULL OR hrl.frn = @frn)
```

**And make sure to set CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False" on your DataSource**

Comment: Only the second to last one did not return anything because I have no blank frn's.  I'm still a little confused on how to put the nullif after the AS line.  Can you provide an example using my sql?

Comment: Also, SearchMaster @business = '', @frn = 'something' works, but not when I run it in the code.

Comment: Ok, I will try this out and let you know

Comment: Ok that worked.  Why would it do that if I am initializing the @business = NULL and @frn = NULL in the procedure and in the code, I am telling it to ConvertEmptyStrings to null.  Also, I am not sure who to give the answer to:  You or Marc.

Comment: Well, I just entered frn into a textbox and left business blank and it still does not work even after making the changes to the stored procedures by doing the NULLIF.

Comment: The NULLIF makes it work in Sql Management Studio when I run the stored procedures

Comment: OK. Time to use Profiler, and look at what the SP is actually getting as a parameter...
Run a Trace with the TSQL_SPs profile and run the page, then let us know what the parameter values are that the SP actually gets.

Comment: Ok, Interesting thing happened.  If I run the profiler and run the page with just one parameter (business or frn), the SearchMaster does not even run in the profiler.  If I run the page with data for both parameters, the procedure runs, so it is not even being executed.

Comment: set CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False" on your data source :)

Comment: I have tried that and it runs when I do that, but my search is enabled by a Search Button click and when I set CancelSelectOnNullParameter = "False", it executes the procedure on page_load.

Comment: and since there is so much data when everything is null, it times out.

Comment: So you only want the search to run if criteria has been provided and the search button has been clicked?